# Set the header option in phd-thesis-template/PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls

Tags: header-footer, templates

I want to select the pageStyleII in phd-thesis-template/PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls. I do not know how to do it.

```
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr} % Define custom header

% Set Fancy Header Command is defined to Load FancyHdr after Geometry is defined
\newcommand{\setFancyHdr}{

\pagestyle{fancy}
\ifPHD@pageStyleI
% Style 1: Sets Page Number at the Top and Chapter/Section Name on LE/RO
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ ##1\ }}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase \rightmark\hspace{0.25em} | 
  \hspace{0.25em} \bfseries{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LE]{ {\bfseries\thepage} \hspace{0.25em} | 
  \hspace{0.25em} \nouppercase \leftmark}


\else
\ifPHD@pageStyleII
% Style 2: Sets Page Number at the Bottom with Chapter/Section Name on LO/RE
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ ##1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries \nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

Could you please help me in this issue?

Best regards,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\documentclass[PageStyleI]{PhDThesisPSnPDF}` and `\documentclass[PageStyleII]{PhDThesisPSnPDF}`, respectively. Probably described in the documentation coming with the class.

Answer (score 2):

The template was recently updated. Quoting from the [README](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template).

> `PhDThesisPSnPDF` defines 3 different page styles (header and footer). The following definition is for `twoside` layout. To choose a page style, include it in the `documentclass` options: `\documentclass[PageStyleI]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}`. Alternatively, page style can be changed by adding `\pagestyle{PageStyleI}` or `\pagestyle{PageStyleII}` in `thesis.tex`. Note: Using `\pagestyle` command will override `documentclass` options when used globally.

---

With the recent changes, it should be more clear where to put stuff.

Many thanks to the maintainer for the quick fix.